# Codeigniter Active Record - Start query at a specific ID?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to setup a Cron Job where it will select a featured video in sequence.

So for example, Video ID 1 is currently the featured video. In a weeks time it will be ID 2. I would then like to load videos 3-18 in after that.

Is this possible using Active Record or an MySQL Statement?

This is quite a hard question to explain, So if you need more info please just comment and I'll get back to you.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Just add a column somewhere in your database named something like `current_video_id` and everytime you run the cronjob update that column with the next ID. Hopefully you know how to make that query.

Comment: Are new videos constantly being added or is there a set list of videos?

Comment: Hi @Daan its a constant list of videos, All in a DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Daan's comment.

Add a new column in your database (`current_featured_id`), it could be `TINYINT` with default value of 0.  If a video is featured the row will have a 1 in the `current_featured_id` column.

In terms of the actual cron job, add in your crontab a command to run the function once a week `* 0 * * 0 featured_vid` (runs every Sunday at midnight)

```
function featured_vid() {
     //get the current featured id
     $featured_id = $this->db->select('video_id')
               ->from('table_name')
               ->where('current_featured_id',1)
               ->get()->row()->video_id;

     $new_featured_id = $featured_id+1;

     $update_featured = array(
         array(
              'video_id' => $featured_id,
              'current_featured_id' => 0
         ),
         array(
              'video_id' => $new_featured_id,
              'current_featured_id' => 1
         ),
     );

     //update your db
     $this->db->update_batch('table_name', $update_featured, 'video_id');
}
```

Comment: Absolutley brilliant @Dan Thanks for that! I will use a current_featured_id and go from there. Cheers for the Cron tips too :-)

Comment: the only thing I'm querying is I'm getting a few errors around your Active Record query.

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

->get()->result()->video_id;

Comment: Try changing that to get()->row()->video_id; I updated the answer, I think that should address that! Or if it's still giving you problems, just do a get->result() and then grab the resulting video_id from your $featured_id